# Reasons Android Studio is not zipAligning my apk

Tags: android, android-studio

I generated a signed apk and wanted to upload it to the play store, but the developer console gives me an error, saying that my apk is not zip aligned.
My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("...")
        keyAlias "..."
        storePassword "..."
        keyPassword "..."
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-my.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.umove.umove'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {...
```

I dont know what the problem is, I dont get an error generating the signed apk, and it worked before.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the gradle plugin `alpha3` upgrade to `alpha4` or downgrade to `alpha2`. It is a bug in `alpha3`. I had the same issue. `alpha4` worked for me.